# "Public Inquiry" or "Public inquiry" – correct capitalisation

Tags: capitalization

What is the correct capitalisation for a "public inquiry" ?

Comment: The words are subject to regular English capitalization rules.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for initial capitals in 'public enquiry/inquiry'. It is a common-noun expression.

Comment: The question is for a Inquiry which differs from enquiry

Comment: @Mark Actually, they are the same.  It's just a spelling variation. BrE vs AmE, and all that jazz.

Comment: @ Mark - As most dictionaries will tell you 'enquiry' and 'inquiry' are simply two different spellings of the same word .

Comment: But not in the legal sense of a *public inquiry*. In the UK, it's *inquiry* and specified in [legislation](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2005/12/contents). A *public enquiry* is a question asked in public; a *public inquiry* is formal inquest-like proceedings with defined terms of reference.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - The British government has chosen to use the **I** spelling for official inquiries. As a result, most British newspapers use that spelling for them. It is not specified in legislation that they must do so. As I said before, "As most dictionaries will tell you 'enquiry' and 'inquiry' are simply two different spellings of the same word". Have you any evidence to support the claim you make for the distinction between *public inquiry* and *public enquiry*?

Comment: OED, draft additions 1993. "Freq. as ***public inquiry.*** A formal or judicial investigation into a matter of public concern, esp. one conducted by a tribunal established for this purpose under a regional or national government department, and granted jurisdictive powers. Also ellipt. or collect. for (members of) the tribunal itself."

Comment: @AndrewLeach. Fine - we have already established that the government used the **I** version of the word. However, at least 60 of the 67 *public **e**nquiry* citations in the British National Corpus are clearly referring to formal or judicial investigations, and none is clearly referring to a question asked in public.